# NSOperationQueue Is Finished Before All Operations Are Completed

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks, nsoperationqueue, nsoperation

I have ***x*** number different task that need to run. Each task is responsible for going out to the internet, downloading some data, process that data, then saving that data.

They all run at the same time on a background thread. Though I would be fine with them running one after the other.

When all 4 tasks are complete I would like to be notified that they have finished in some fashion.

However,  `NSOperationQueue` is firing off the completed queue before any of the other actual operations have started.

**My Log with the current setup:**

> fetchMyData: completionOperation YES
>
> FILE: MySet1 CREATED
>
> FILE: MySet2 CREATED
>
> FILE: MySet3 CREATED
>
> FILE: MySet4 CREATED

***Is there a better way to chain the operations together and fully waiting on all of them to complete before firing the final operation?***

**Here is what I am doing:**

```
- (void) timeToUpdate {
    [self fetchMyData:^(BOOL done) {
        NSLog(@"fetchMyData: completionOperation : %@", done ? @"YES":@"NO");
    }];


- (void) fetchMyData: (void(^)(BOOL done)) completion {
    
    NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    
    NSOperation *completionOperation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
        NSLog(@"fetchMyData: completionOperation");
        completion(true);
    }];
    
    NSOperation *operation;
    

    operation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
        [self downloadDataSet:@"MySet1"];
    }];
    
    [completionOperation addDependency:operation];
    [queue addOperation:operation];
    

    operation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
        [self downloadDataSet:@"MySet2"];
    }];
    
    [completionOperation addDependency:operation];
    [queue addOperation:operation];
    

    operation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
        [self downloadDataSet:@"MySet3"];
    }];
    
    [completionOperation addDependency:operation];
    [queue addOperation:operation];
    

    operation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
        [self downloadDataSet:@"MySet4"];
    }];
    
    [completionOperation addDependency:operation];
    [queue addOperation:operation];
    
    [queue addOperation:completionOperation];
}

//The below is just abstract sudo code that works and does its job of downloading, processing and saving the data.

- (void) downloadDataSet:(SomeSet) {
    
    [NSURLSessionUploadTask  uploadTaskWithRequest:task 
                                    fromData: Someset 
                                   completionHandler: {
                    process(set);
    }]
}

- process:(data) {
    doSomethignWithData(data)
//then
    write(data)

}
- write(data) {
    //save to file system, sql, coredata whatever
    
    if(success){
        NSLog(@"FILE: data CREATED");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your operations are calling `uploadTaskWithRequest:fromData: completionHandler:`, an asynchronous operation which returns before its job has been completed. What you should do is to look into using an *asynchronous* `NSOperation`; basically you override the `isAsynchronous` method to return `YES`, and then you set the operation's `finished` property when `uploadTaskWithRequest:fromData: completionHandler:`'s completion handler is called. This way, any operations that depend on your download operations will wait until they are actually complete before firing.

Here's a handy set of async `NSOperation` subclasses that I use; it's Swift, not Objective-C, but it illustrates the concept and should provide a decent pseudocode for you to build your own implementation.

```
open class AsyncOperation: Operation {
    override open var isAsynchronous: Bool { return true }
    override open var isExecuting: Bool { return self.state == .started }
    override open var isFinished: Bool { return self.state == .done }

    private enum State {
        case initial
        case started
        case done
    }

    private var state: State = .initial {
        willSet {
            // due to a legacy issue, these have to be strings. Don't make them key paths.
            self.willChangeValue(forKey: "isExecuting")
            self.willChangeValue(forKey: "isFinished")
        }
        didSet {
            self.didChangeValue(forKey: "isFinished")
            self.didChangeValue(forKey: "isExecuting")
        }
    }

    public init(name: String? = nil) {
        super.init()

        if #available(macOS 10.10, *) {
            self.name = name
        }
    }

    final override public func start() {
        self.state = .started

        self.main {
            if case .done = self.state {
                fatalError("AsyncOperation completion block called twice")
            }

            self.state = .done
        }
    }

    final override public func main() {}

    open func main(completionHandler: @escaping () -> ()) {
        fatalError("Subclass must override main(completionHandler:)")
    }
}

open class AsyncBlockOperation: AsyncOperation {
    private let closure: (_ completionHandler: @escaping () -> ()) -> ()

    public init(name: String? = nil, closure: @escaping (_ completionHandler: @escaping () -> ()) -> ()) {
        self.closure = closure
        super.init(name: name)
    }

    override open func main(completionHandler: @escaping () -> ()) {
        self.closure(completionHandler)
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could eschew the use of `NSOperation` and use a `dispatch_group_t` to get similar behavior; call `dispatch_group_enter()` initially, call `dispatch_group_leave()` in the download task's completion handler, and use `dispatch_notify()` to run your completion block.

Comment: This is in Swift. Do you have an Obj-c example?

Comment: @user-44651 No, but as I said, you can use it as a decent pseudocode to build your own implementation.

Comment: How to use this please? @CharlesSrstka

Comment: Great stuff! Some pseudo example code would be useful